# Why is Rspec conflicting with RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I am getting error messages when I run rspec spec.  When I read the terminal output it looks like there might be something going on with RVM.  Everything is up to date.  If anyone can offer guidance about these errors I'd appreciate it. I am also including the page controller I built too, but I am following a tutorial and so it's basically just a retyped copy.

```
    Z-Kidds-MacBook-Air:sample_app zkidd$ rspec spec
/Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:306:in `load': /Users/zkidd/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:87: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting tCONSTANT (SyntaxError)
...                      ::content => "#{@base_title} +  | Cont...
...                               ^
/Users/zkidd/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:87: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
/Users/zkidd/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:103: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
    from /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:306:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:306:in `map'
    from /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:306:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
    from /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
    from /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in `run'
    from /Users/zkidd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
Z-Kidds-MacBook-Air:sample_app zkidd$
```

Here is the pages_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do
  render_views

  before(:each) do
    #
    # Define @base_title here.
    #
  end

  describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'home'
      response.should have_selector("title",
                                    :content => "#{@base_title} +  | Home")
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'contact'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should have_selector("title",
                                    ::content => "#{@base_title} +  | Contact")
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'about'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'about'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'about'
      response.should have_selector("title",
                                    :content => "#{@base_title} +  | About")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::content =>` should be `:content =>`

Comment: Thanks jdl . . . I should have caught that.

Comment: Be sure to remember this situation, if you see syntax errors in your traceback, you can be sure you've messed up typing something in your code, the filename is added as well so you should know where to look :-)

Answer (score 1):

if you are working with textmate, you should probably try to use dr-nics ruby and rails bundles. they have a builtin syntax checker!

https://github.com/drnic/